# Postgres List Partition With Linux Epoch

Tags: postgresql, datetime, query-optimization, partitioning, epoch

Postgres 12 on GCP. column numeric(19) stores epoch date like 1668368711000.

wish to have the following:

1. Range partition for each day (or hour), [I will stress test both day or hour partition to check what work best for my case]
2. Rule (or equivalent) that will create a new partition if not exists when new data insert. i.e. (don't have to create partitions manually in advance or with a scheduler)
3. drop old partitions, older than n days/hours(wish to drop old partitions, I will prefer the scheduler for that)

Can experts advise me on what should be the best and most efficient solution for my case?

Thanks

Comment: Those are millisecond UNIX-epoch timestamps (Javascript style). You can do `DIV(ts, 86400000)` to partition by day, or `DIV(ts, 3600000)` to partition by hour, and you'll get calendar days or hours in UTC. (If your timestamp discipline includes leap seconds, your day and hour boundaries will be a tiny bit off.) And, it's better to ask just one question in each StackOverflow post.

Comment: @O.Jones
Thanks for DIV directions and thanks for the advice.